# how to put textview side by side?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

i have this code below. i want the output to be side by side. what should i do?

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView29"
    android:text="Number of guest(s) : "   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView26"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView29"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enclose the text views in a linear layout, like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have done that but it still not working.

Comment: Could you post your current xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to a new sub layout "linear layout" and use android:orientation="horizontal"

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your hopefully desired result, I added a second layout to hopefully help you see how to use layouts, I also included where you can cut out the part you dont need.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView29"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView26"
                android:text="Number of guest(s) : "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView29"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
 //Below not needed
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView26"
                android:text="Number of guest(s) : "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView29"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
//Above not needed
    </LinearLayout>
```